# texdoc vs CTAN MANIFEST.md

Tags: ctan, texdoc, manifest

I would like to know if with the following `CTAN` manifest build by `l3build`, the command `texdoc bdoc` will open the `bdoc-FR.pdf` file?

```markdown
# Manifest for bdoc

This file is a listing of all files considered to be part of this package.
It is automatically generated with `l3build manifest`.


## Repository manifest

The following groups list the files included in the development repository of the package.
Files listed with a ‘†’ marker are included in the TDS but not CTAN files, and files listed
with ‘‡’ are included in both.

### Text files

Plain text files included as documentation or metadata.

* MANIFEST.md ‡
* README.md ‡

### Derived files

The files created by ‘unpacking’ the package sources. This typically includes
`.sty` and `.cls` files created from DocStrip `.dtx` files.

* bdoc-locale-english.cfg.sty ‡
* bdoc-locale-french.cfg.sty ‡
* bdoc.sty ‡


## TDS manifest

The following groups list the files included in the TeX Directory Structure used to install
the package into a TeX distribution.

### Source files (TDS)

All files included in the `bdoc/source` directory.

* bdoc-FR.pdf 
* bdoc-locale-english.cfg.sty 
* bdoc-locale-french.cfg.sty 
* bdoc.sty 

### TeX files (TDS)

All files included in the `bdoc/tex` directory.

* bdoc-locale-english.cfg.sty 
* bdoc-locale-french.cfg.sty 
* bdoc.sty 

### Doc files (TDS)

All files included in the `bdoc/doc` directory.

* MANIFEST.md 
* README.md 
* bdoc-demo.tex 


## CTAN manifest

The following group lists the files included in the CTAN package.

### CTAN files

* MANIFEST.md 
* README.md 
* bdoc-FR.pdf 
* bdoc-demo.tex 
* bdoc-locale-english.cfg.sty 
* bdoc-locale-french.cfg.sty 
* bdoc.sty
```

Comment: not sure of the details but I think the mappings have to be set up by the texdoc maintainers, bdoc.pdf or bdoc-doc.pdf would work by the general heuristics, not so sure about bdoc-FR.pdf, someone knowing texdoc details may answer....

Comment: The TDS layout looks wrong. How is `bdoc-FR.pdf` created? Is it really source? You're listing the same files as both source and derived (e.g. the `.sty` files), but they can't be both. If you don't use the `.dtx`/`.ins`, your `.sty` files are presumably source and not derived. I'm not sure whether `texdoc` looks outside the `doc` directory.

Comment: @cfr The `PDF` file is a doc that I compile automatically before working with `l3build`, but for the moment I fail to put in the doc, so I will investigate this failure of my `l3build` setting: look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/701859/6880 .

Comment: Why? I mean, why do that separately? Then you just have the problem of editing the generated files e.g. the list of source and derived files will be wrong and need correcting. That seems like a recipe for errors. (By which I mean: *I* would screw that up.)

Comment: What's the point of using the suffix if there is only one document? Where documentation uses language suffixes, it is usually because a package offers documentation in multiple languages and in different files. There it makes sense. But if you want `texdoc` to open that file regardless, the suffix just adds to the complexity for `texdoc` and makes it more likely that doesn't happen. Also, judging by `texdoc.cnf`, language suffixes are generally lowercase.

Comment: @cfr I plan to translate my doc in English. I note that I have to use lowercase suffixes.

Comment: I didn't say you have to. I said looking in the default config, lowercase suffixes seemed usual. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your MANIFEST strictly, if `bdoc-FR.pdf` is placed in the source tree, Texdoc will not be able to find this PDF file. Instead, it will find `MANIFEST.md` and `README.md` from the doc tree with lower scores. On the other hand, if `bdoc-FR.pdf` is placed in the doc tree, Texdoc will recognize it as a package document and display it as a top priority.

Key points to consider:

- Currently, Texdoc does not support searching in the source tree.
- The case of suffixes (uppercase or lowercase) does not matter.
- When uploading to CTAN, the CTAN team or maintainers who incorporate it into TeX Live may adjust the file placement within TDS or request changes. It is best to follow their guidance.

---

Texdoc primarily searches only within the doc tree for documents. An exception is made when searching for `PKGNAME.sty`, where it will display the `.sty` file from the tex tree. Therefore, if a document file (`bdoc-FR.pdf`) is placed in the source tree, Texdoc will not be able to find the file. However, even if this package with the current manifest is uploaded to CTAN, it is likely that corrections to the file locations in the TDS will be made at some point before it is incorporated into TeX distributions. There have been [a suggestion](https://github.com/TeX-Live/texdoc/issues/47) that Texdoc should fall back to searching the source tree if no appropriate documents are found in the doc tree, but implementing this would require significant changes to Texdoc's file search and scoring scheme, and may not be realized soon. In any case, for this particular situation, it seems unnecessary to place the document in the source tree instead of the doc tree.

If the document file (`bdoc-FR.pdf`) is placed in the doc tree, Texdoc will recognize it as the main French document for the bdoc package. If no other language documents exist, Texdoc will display the file with the highest priority. While language code suffixes are commonly written in lowercase, Texdoc does not differentiate between uppercase and lowercase in file names, so this will not affect search results.