# l3build, CTAN and PDF versions of demo files

Tags: ctan, l3build

Is it a good idea to distribute the PDF version of the demo files? If so, how can I do this?

```lua
-- build.lua

module = "bdoc"

sourcefiles      = {"code/*.sty", "code/*.pdf"}
typesetdemofiles = {"demos/*.tex"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer probably means the question is "opinion based" and not suitable for the site but anyway...

I don't think it's a good idea to distribute demos on ctan (and so texlive/miktex) at all.

Users of your package may try `texdoc bdoc` and get a top level documentation but anything else probably won't be found if you distribute it in that way

Even the very trivial one page demo file that comes with latex2e, `small2e.tex`, is hardly usable these days.

`small2e.tex` (but not, to answer the question, `small2e.pdf`) is in the base latex directory in the input path of all documents so you can, on the comandline, run

```
pdflatex small2e
```

and see your first example latex run and generate `small2e.pdf` in your current directory. Except for most users these days they do not use the commandline (or are using something like Overleaf that does not have a commandline). To run `small2e` with latex they need to open something like `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/small2e.tex` in their editor and press "run" or some such, but then it will probably fail as they don't have write access to that directory so you need to copy the file to a temporary place first, and suddenly the trivial example is not trivial at all.

It makes sense to have demos and test files in your github sources but you do not need to package them as part of the release, you can separately make tutorials and demos available, perhaps by running a github-pages site directly from your source repository.

This could for example offer people the chance to run the demos online and see pdfs being generated, see for example the demos at

https://davidcarlisle.github.io/latexcgi/

That same server is used to power the examples at [learnlatex.org](https://learnlatex.org/) or the TikZ examples at [tikz.net](https://tikz.net/)

Comment: Very good advice, I'm convinced.

Comment: @projetmbc It's possible to make the files available from within a single documentation file, though. But, really, I think this answer is just a bit over generalised. In many cases, it's probably about right. But in other cases, I think it can make sense to include examples in the package. For cases where the examples might depend on the version, for instance, it is much easier if you don't have to figure out which is the correct version of the file. I also find things like Biblatex's example database very useful in part because I know it's part of a standard install. `pgfplots` comes to mind.

Comment: @cfr well yes as I said in the opening line, it's all a bit general and opinion based, certainly room for another answer giving different use cases.

Comment: I wouldn't dare.